# Angular2 - traceur not found after adding hltv-api npm

Tags: angular, npm, npm-install

I've just added hltv-api npm package by npm install directly into hltv-api folder. 
I've tried to import it at my component.ts file with:

```
    import {
      getNews,
      getResults
    } from 'hltv-api';
```

And made my systemjs.config.js file like:

```
    /**
     * System configuration for Angular samples
     * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
     */
    (function (global) {
      System.config({
        paths: {
          // paths serve as alias
          'npm:': 'node_modules/'
        },
        // map tells the System loader where to look for things
        map: {
          // our app is within the app folder
          app: 'app',
          // angular bundles
          '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
          '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
          '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
          '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
          '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
          '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
          '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
          '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
          // other libraries
          'rxjs':                      'npm:rxjs',
          'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js'
          'hltv-api' : 'npm:hltv-api'
        },
        // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
        packages: {
          app: {
            main: './main.js',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
          },
          rxjs: {
            defaultExtension: 'js'
          },
          'hltv-api': {
            main: './src/index.js',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
          }
        }
      });
    })(this);
```

It's strange to pull index.js from src, but after npm install I only got those folders. Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for being quite late on answering this, hope it's still helpful.

Hltv-api is a node.js module, you should serve the API with node. I've updated the original repo, you should use the latest version or module to expect working, since hltv is updating website which affects the scraping system. From now (v1.2.1), you can see [sample app](https://github.com/dajk/hltv-api/tree/master/demo-app) how to create simple server and serve the API. I'll work on documentation as well as try to expand API with another features.

For now, feel free to open an issue, suggest or ask anything on [Github's repo](https://github.com/dajk/hltv-api).